# Squire for your recursive SSH adventures

Tags: bash, linux, shell, sh, ssh

*One day I used to SSH to lots of machines to do some administrative tasks. I constantly used `l` to list directories just like I do on my own machines. Guess what, that doesn't work. There were no any usable aliases! So I opened a code editor...*

## xssh

This script will connect to remote host via `ssh` and source specified rc file (similar to `.bashrc`). It is possible to call `xssh` once again to go deeper, so one may say it is self-reproducing.

I use it for a year or so, code works fine. Things I worry about:

- fallback behaviour when there is no `bash` shell
- `base64` is required on host system
- to be used as `alias ssh=xssh` script must behave similary to `ssh`
- overal code style and consistence
- in last `HEREDOC` I try to determine if current shell is `bash`. If not, I try to fallback to normal shell (w/o `~/.xssh` usage). Not sure it is done the right way.

I aim to make this code go public, so I need your review and recommendations.

```
#!/bin/sh

# xssh - squire for your recursive ssh adventures

# This tiny script will follow you in your ssh adventures,
# just like squires serve their knights.
# It will run commands (think .bashrc) on remote systems and
# follow while you travel from host to host no matter how far
# the road takes you.


# xssh runs ssh and sources your ~/.xssh right after successfull
# login to bash. More over xssh tries to be "self-reproducing"
# so you can use it again to ssh from remote system.
# As stated by shebang xssh doesn't require bash on host
# system but it requires one on the remote.


XSSH_RC=~/.xssh  # Your .xssh file, that will be sourced on remote system
XSSH_SELF="$0"   # Path to this script (change this to absolute path,
                 # if it doesn't work as expected)


SSH_HOST=
SSH_ARGS=

base64_encode() {
    {
        command -v openssl >/dev/null 2>&1 && openssl enc -base64 ||
        command -v base64 >/dev/null 2>&1 && base64
    } | tr -d '\n'
}

base64_decode() {
    sed -e "s/.\{64\}/&\n/g" | {
        command -v openssl >/dev/null 2>&1 && openssl enc -base64 -d ||
        command -v base64 >/dev/null 2>&1 && base64 -d
    }
}

if ! [ -t 1 ]; then
    # Not in terminal, fallback to ssh
    ssh "$@"
    exit $?
fi

if ! [ -r "$XSSH_RC" ] && ! [ -n "$_XSSH_RC" ]; then
    # Nothing to source, fallback to ssh
    ssh "$@"
    exit $?
fi

parse_args() {
    while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
        case "$1" in
        -b | -c | -D | -E | -e | \
        -F | -I | -i | -L | -l | \
        -m | -O | -o | -p | -Q | \
        -R | -S | -W | -w )
            SSH_ARGS="$SSH_ARGS $1 $2"; shift ;;
        -*)
            SSH_ARGS="$SSH_ARGS $1" ;;
        *)
            if [ -z "$SSH_HOST" ]; then
                SSH_HOST="$1"
            else
                # `command` argument
                # no need to use xssh
                return 1
            fi
        esac
        shift
    done
}

parse_args "$@" || {
    # Failed parsing arguments (`command` argument?), fallback to ssh
    ssh "$@"; exit $?;
}

# Store .xsshrc contents in `$_XSSH_SOURCE`
if [ -z "$_XSSH_RC" ]; then
    export _XSSH_RC=$(cat "$XSSH_RC" | base64_encode)
    { _XSSH_SOURCE=$(base64_encode) ; } <<HEREDOC
_xssh_func() {
    $(cat "$XSSH_SELF")
}
HEREDOC
fi

# Bootstrap script
# This will run .xsshrc and create xssh command
{ _XSSH_INIT=$(base64_encode) ; } <<HEREDOC
base64_decode() {
    sed -e "s/.\{64\}/&\n/g" | {
        command -v openssl >/dev/null 2>&1 && openssl enc -base64 -d ||
        command -v base64 >/dev/null 2>&1 && base64 -d
    }
}
export _XSSH_RC="$_XSSH_RC"
export _XSSH_SOURCE="$_XSSH_SOURCE"
. <(printf '%s' "\$_XSSH_SOURCE" | base64_decode)
. <(printf '%s' "\$_XSSH_RC" | base64_decode)
alias xssh=_xssh_func
HEREDOC

# Snippet to run bootstap with bash shell
# Used with eval, watch for `;`
{ _XSSH_BASH=$(base64_encode) ; } <<HEREDOC
_xssh_init() {
    \$BASH --rcfile <(printf '%s' "$_XSSH_INIT" | base64_decode) -i;
};
HEREDOC

# This script will try to run bash specific code
# If the system is not infected by bash, run login shell instead
{ _XSSH_SAFE_CMD=$(cat) ; } <<HEREDOC
base64_decode() {
    sed -e "s/.\{64\}/&\n/g" | {
        command -v openssl >/dev/null 2>&1 && openssl enc -base64 -d ||
        command -v base64 >/dev/null 2>&1 && base64 -d
    }
};
case "\$SHELL" in
 */bash*)
  eval \$(printf '%s' "$_XSSH_BASH" | base64_decode)
        ;;
    *)
        test -x "\$SHELL" && exec "\$SHELL" -il || exec /bin/sh -il
        ;;
esac;
_xssh_init;
HEREDOC


# Let the journey begin
ssh -t $SSH_ARGS "$SSH_HOST" "$_XSSH_SAFE_CMD"
```

Example `~/.xssh` rc file:

```
alias l='ls -hAlt --color=auto --group-directories-first '
alias ssh='xssh '

# I use `vis` editor, it is somewhat simular to `vim`
alias vis=vim

# Up and Down will complete history in bash
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'

. ~/.bashrc

PS1="\u@\[\033[1;30m\]\h\[\033[0m\] \W "

# I use st terminal, but probably there is no `st.info` on remote host
TERM=xterm-256color
```

There is simular project [sshrc](https://github.com/Russell91/sshrc) with different goals. In particular `xssh` tries to be "recursive" and won't leave or create any files (even in `/tmp`) on remote hosts.

Comment: Isn't the logic in `if ! [ -r "$XSSH_RC" ] && ! [ -n "_$XSSH_RC" ]; then` erroneous? The `-n "_$..."` has a literal `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `ssh "$@"; exit $?;` can be simply `exec ssh "$@"`.  That's objectively better, because now if `ssh` receives a signal, the parent process (probably your interactive shell) will be informed correctly of which signal and whether a core dump was created.  (In any case, `exit` without an argument will implicitly use `$?` as status).

Similarly, the final line would be better as `exec ssh …`.

`base64` has a `-w` or `--wrap` argument that accepts `0` to disable line-wrapping; `openssl -enc -A -base64` also produces single-line output (you'll need to also pass `-A` on the decode command).  That lets you eliminate the `tr` from encode and the `sed` from decode.

```
base64_encode() {
    if openssl exit 2>/dev/null
    then openssl enc -base64 -A
    else base64 -w 0
    fi
}

base64_decode() {
    if openssl exit 2>/dev/null
    then openssl enc -base64 -A -d
    else base64 -d
    fi
}
```

An answer comment says that we need to work with OpenBSD's `base64` which doesn't have the same `-w` option.  That is an excellent reason to include a **comment** to explain why we're not doing things this obvious way, and prevent future maintainers inadvertently breaking something that works.  That's exactly what comments are good for!

You can save re-typing these definitions in the here-documents, by extracting their definitions from `set` output (but only if you make this a Bash script):

```
$(set | sed -n '/^base64_..code /,/^}/p')
```

Did you consider `printf %q` as an alternative encoding?  I think that's specific to GNU coreutils, so might not be acceptable to you.  In particular, you'd need to avoid the built-in `printf` in shells such as Dash.

The example file really shouldn't have terminal-specific codes before you've tested `$TERM`.  Preferably, use `tput` to insert the appropriate codes for whatever terminal is found.

Comment: IIRC OpenBSD `base64 -w` doesn't work similar. Thats the reason `tr` and  `sed` landed there. Nice trick about `HEREDOC`, but I am bound to `sh` shell (on host system). `printf %q` may be a nice player, but I am not sure how many systems have both `bash` **and** GNU coreutils together. Doesn't quite understand your last paragraph.

Comment: The compatibility considerations are definitely worth commenting in your code (to prevent future readers making the same suggestions as me).  Remember the mantra: "explain *why*; make *how* explain itself."  To explain the last paragraph - `\033[1;30m` and `\033[0m` are VT-style terminal escape codes.  Not all terminals are VT, so use `tput` to generate the correct codes instead of those hard-coded strings.  I've just noticed override of `TERM` to something that may be wrong just afterwards - that looks risky, too.